# Include header file only if it is available in C?

Tags: c, macros, include, c-preprocessor, header-files

I want to add logic for pthread into a small profiling library I'm writing for C. However, I only want to execute the logic relevant to pthread if pthread is available.

Is there a programmatic way to do this using preprocessor directives?

I imagine it would look something like:

```c
#ifdef pthread_h
#include <pthread.h>
#endif

. . .


#ifdef pthread_h
// pthread specific logic here
#endif
```

But the part I'm uncertain about and don't know what to do with is

```c
#ifdef pthread_h
```

If I haven't included `pthread.h` yet, `pthread_h` isn't available. Right?

Is there a way to include a header file only if it's available? Perhaps I could achieve the result I'm looking for that way.

---

My desired result is to include information about the current Thread ID in the profiling data, but only if the library has pthread available to call `pthread_self()`.

Comment: `Linked` **!=** `included`. It is something different. Nothing is linked compile time. Libraries are `linked` during linking which is happening after the compilation and usually is done by the separate program called `linker`

Comment: Apart from the misplaced wording regarding the linking process. Why doesn't the provided example work for you? Why and because of what are you uncertain in particular?

Comment: The provided example doesn't work for me because I don't know where `pthread_h` would have been defined if it can't be defined until i include `pthread.h`. 

Am I able to attempt to include a file but fail if it's not found? Perhaps I could do this based on available headers instead of available libraries.

Comment: @P__J__ i've modified the question, hopefully, the terminology makes a little more sense now. I'm not incredibly familiar with C, hence why I'm here.

Comment: Read about [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*Is there a way to include a header file only if it's available? Perhaps I could achieve the result I'm looking for that way.*"

Yes. You can use i.e. the [`__has_include`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html) macro, if your compiler supports it:

```
#if defined __has_include
#  if __has_include (<pthread.h>)
#    include <pthread.h>
#  endif
#endif

...

#if defined __has_include
#  if __has_include (<pthread.h>)
#    // pthread specific logic here
#  endif
#endif
```

---

Side Note:

- > "... if pthread has actually been linked at compile time."

The linking process is not done at compile time. It comes after the compilation. And the C preprocessor does its work even before the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this solution that I like the most. It seems to be the most portable and the most straight forward.

Simply instruct the user to compile with `-D PROF_WITH_PTHREA=1` when compiling if they wish to use pthread and then within the C source check for that preprocessor directive before using pthread for anything.

```sh
$ gcc -I./ -o test text.c -lpthread -D PROF_WITH_PTHREAD=1
```

```c
#ifdef PROF_WITH_PTHREAD
#include <pthread.h>
#endif

. . .

#ifdef PROF_WITH_PTHREAD
// pthread specific logic here
#endif
```

---

While this doesn't check if a library is available or check if a header is available, it achieves the result I wanted and does it in a very straight forward and simple way.

Comment: You should cite the source of the quote, Nathan. In this way you can help others finding the solution's source you found.

Comment: I see that you use GCC. Just out of interest: Doesn't the `__has_include` macro as shown in my answer work for you? It is supported in GCC and achieves exact the thing you was looking for - to check whether a library is available or not directly with preprocessor macros without any additional compiler options like `-D PROF_WITH_PTHREAD=1` (except of course `-pthread`). What is the exact advantage of this method causing you to prefer it? I can't see that in the answer. - "*It seems to be the most portable and the most straight forward.*" gives the impression of an opinion.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio it's not actually a quote. It's just a poor choice in formatting. I'll fix that.

And I think allowing the use of a compile time definition of a preprocessing directive is more portable than requiring the user to use GCC.